# Trouble getting PHP fsockopen to ignore errors

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm setting up reporting on my PHP script with etsy's open source [statsd library](https://github.com/etsy/statsd). 
I'm basing my connection on their given example, but I'm running into an issue where it seems like `fsockopen` is ignoring `try/catch` and is printing its errors.

Everything works grand when the statsd server is up and running - but if it's down or the php script cannot connect to it:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
Name or service not known
```

I even attempted adding `@` in front of fsockopen, but no dice. It also seems to be completely ignoring the timeout setting, as it takes about 20 seconds to return the error:

```
        try {
            $host = 'stats.thisserverisdown.com';
            $port = '8125';
            if ( $fp = @fsockopen("udp://$host", $port, $errno, $errstr, 1) ) {
                if (!(get_resource_type($fp) == 'stream')) { return false; }
                stream_set_timeout($fp,1);
                stream_set_blocking($fp,false);
                foreach ($sampledData as $stat => $value) {
                    @fwrite($fp, "$stat:$value");
                }
                @fclose($fp);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fsockopen` is not throwing the error. Because `fsockopen` has to resolve the hostname you provided, it calls `getaddinfo()`, which is failing.

Try supplying an IP address, or:

```
fsockopen( @"udp://$host", ...
```